# Beginner question about Kubernetes and Magento 2

Tags: magento2, docker

i followed a tutorial to install magento 2 with kubernetes using alexcheng1982 / docker-magento2 package.
But the magento installation fails due to a database problem:

```
[ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Cannot process definition to array for type set in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php:57
```

So now I would like to inspect the tables via phpmyadmin and work on the files with phpstorm
but
how do I reach the magento files that presumably will be in the virtual machine created with minikube?

In practice, how should I set up phpstorm to have the project files synchronized with those of the virtual machine?

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

please provide link for that tutorial.

I would suggest you to try to setup magento ecosystem on your local machine (if you have not already).

If you want to have a look at container content search "docker exec" or kubernetes alternative.

Synchronization with phpstorm can be achieved via binded volumes.